# Searching HTML DOM tree with search form

Tags: html, dom, model-view-controller, umbraco

I have a page that's like a dictionary. I have used Umbraco to generate the words in the page and each word has a description. It's nutrition words so it's like 'salt', 'vitamin B12' etc. Now, I have to create a search bar that will search for those words and will return the results and I need it to be fuzzy. I don't need to use Umbraco per say but I am doing the project so far using MVC and razor. I have no idea how to make it search the page.

```
<div class="row">

            @foreach (var item in Model.Content.Descendants("lekseisDiatrofikouLeksikou"))
            {





                <div class="col-sm-3 styled">
                    <button data-id="@id" type="button" class="btn">
                        @(item.GetPropertyValue<string>("leksi"))
                    </button>
                    <div id="@("button-wrapper"+id)" class="col-xs-12 styled2 text-center nopadding">
                        @Html.Raw(item.GetPropertyValue<string>("perigrafiLeksis"))
                    </div>
                </div>
                id++;
            }

        </div>
```

This is the loop I'm using to produce the words in the dictionary. This produces a bootstrap col-sm-3 for each word. I literally have no idea how to search these words. Should I search through the DOM tree in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! Definitely :) In Umbraco you have Examine / Lucene indexes to enable you fast and easy search feature. It's made to make search easier. You can still perform this operation inside page descendants, but examine will be much better in this case.

Check the introduction and details here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/searching/examine/ and then go to https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/searching/examine/overview-explanation to check how to use Fluent API and construct the query with which you'll be able to search only inside nodes that interests you.

It may look like this:

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var searchCriteria = ExamineManager.Instance.CreateSearchCriteria();

var valuesToSearch = new string[] { "salt", "vitamin" };

searchCriteria.NodeTypeAlias("AliasOfYourDictionaryItemDocumentType");
searchCriteria.GroupedOr(new List<string>() { "propertyAliasInWhichWeWantToSearch" }, valuesToSearch);

var results = umbracoHelper.TypedSearch(searchCriteria);
```

And you'll have a list of items returned from the index search. It's untested, but hopefully will aim you to the right direction. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I can't add stuff to the index every time the client adds another word. Maybe I didn't phrase it correctly, but I have doctypes for each word without template. The properties inside are generated automatically when the client adds a new doctype. I'm not supposed to interfere with the site again once it's done, which means I won't be able to update code. It needs to do it by itself. I appreciate your comment though. I really do.

Comment: This is automatically added to default (internal, external) indexes, you don't need to do anything. So, if any editor will be placing new content in Content section, items in index will be automatically updated. You can test queries and check what's in the index on Developer section and tab "Examine Management".

Comment: As far as I know, even the default indexes must be updated manually on Examine (I've used it before that's why I have this notion in my head). Do you mean I should index the doctype and it will search on its own after that?

Comment: Umbraco has own indexes and actions which are taking care of updates & rebuilds after each publish / unpublish action on node(s). So, by default, you're able to perform searches inside all your document types etc. You just need to profile and adjust your search criteria and query to retrieve as much accurate results as you want have. Chech this Examine dashboard in Umbraco and just see what's inside each index and play with publishing / unpublishing of nodes. Just remember that sometimes rebuild may take some time and it's asynchronous.

Comment: Ah didn't know that. Thanks a lot. I'll do that.